# Ways of filling 10 places with number from [1..10] such that digit at ith place has value atmost 1 more than the largest value at 1..to ith place

Tags: algorithm, permutation

for example if we consider the case for 3 places with numbers from [1..3]..we can do it in 5 ways:

```
1 1 1
1 1 2
1 2 1
1 2 2 
1 2 3
```

In second place we cant have 3 as the difference between 2nd and 1 first place will be more than 1.

Any place (say i ) can have value atmost 1 more than the LARGEST value at its previous positions (i.e from 1 ..i-1)

Comment: Are you looking for an algorithm to create all combinations possible for x places? Do you want a validation algorithm to make sure a combination matches the criteria? Or do you want to know just the number of possible combinations?

Comment: Why is `2 2 2` not allowed in your example?

Comment: I suppose the first value in all cases has to be 1. As the value before the first probably is counted as 0. But that's just my interpretation.

Comment: Assuming that you only care about the number of combinations. I've started working on a list of what the function would return: f(1) = 1, f(2) = 2, f(3) = 5, f(4) = 15. The function is recursive, it can take the results from the previous value and add some. Just gotta find out what to add.

Comment: http://www.codechef.com/APRIL12/problems/PANSTACK .

Comment: In my humble opinion, people should refrain from asking SO to solve problems of currently-running contests for them, especially without disclosure. I would suggest closing this and reposting it once the April challenge is over. However I don't see anything wrong with this since CodeChef does not seem to have any explicit collaboration policy. Though please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: It is impossible, if we take the challenge by word. The maximum at position 1, if we take elements from position s(0, 1) might be 42, so at pos i, it has to be at least 43, but the condition was, that it is 42. If it is 43, it has to be 44 and so on.

Comment: It's not 1 more than the value at its previous position it's one more than the largest of ALL previous previous positions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let `dp[i, j] = how many possibilities of generating i positions such that the max is j, following the restrictions`.

We have:

```
dp[0, 0] = dp[1, 1] = 1
dp[i, j > i] = dp[i > 0, 0] = 0
dp[2, 1] = 1*dp[1, 1] + dp[1, 0] <- add 1 at the end
dp[2, 2] = dp[1, 2] + dp[1, 1] <- add 2 at the end

dp[3, 1] = 1*dp[2, 1] + dp[2, 0] <- add 1 at the end
dp[3, 2] = 2*dp[2, 2] + dp[2, 1]  <- add 2 at the end
dp[3, 3] = 3*dp[2, 3] + dp[2, 2] <- add 1, 2 or 3 at the end
sum = 1 + 2 + 1 + 1 = 5

dp[4, 1] = 1*dp[3, 1] + dp[3, 0]
dp[4, 2] = 2*dp[3, 2] + dp[3, 1]
dp[4, 3] = 3*dp[3, 3] + dp[3, 2]
dp[4, 4] = 4*dp[3, 4] + dp[3, 3] 
sum = 1 + 6 + 1 + 3 + 3 + 1 = 15 

dp[i, j] = j*dp[i - 1, j] + (1)
           dp[i - 1, j - 1] (2)
answer = dp[n, 1] + dp[n, 2] + ... + dp[n, n]
```

**(1)**: We have the max `j` for the first `i - 1` elements already, so we can put anything on position `i` as long as this doesn't break the rule. This anything is clearly: `1, ..., j`.

**(2)**: We don't have the max `j` for the first `i - 1`, so we must make it so, by appending `j` to all those with a max of `j - 1`. Note that if the max of `1 ... i - 1` is `< j - 1`, we cannot make the max of `1 ... i` to be `j` while following the restrictions of the problem, so there is no point considering any `dp[i - 1, k < j - 1]`.

This can be implemented in `O(n^2)`, which should be fast enough for for `n` up to about 5000 on a decent CPU. The memory used is also `O(n^2)`.